# How to solve truncated text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

There is a problem that the writing doesn't come out when the content of the writing is long. I don't know how can I fix this ploblem with my code... I used firebase database service.

[image]

This is my code.

```
   Widget _buildBody() {
    return SafeArea(
     child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       stream: Firestore.instance.collection('post').snapshots(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (!snapshot.hasData) {
           return _buildNoPostBody();
              }
            return _buildHasPostBody(snapshot.data.documents);
           }
         ),
       );
     }

      Widget _buildNoPostBody() {
       return SingleChildScrollView(

          );
        }

      Widget _buildHasPostBody(List<DocumentSnapshot> documents) {
      final myPosts = documents
      .where((doc) => doc['email'] == user.email)
      .take(999999999999999)
      .toList();

      final otherPosts = documents
     .where((doc) => doc['email'] != user.email)
     .take(999999999999999)
     .toList();

      myPosts.addAll(otherPosts);

      return ListView(
         children: myPosts.map((doc) => FeedWidget(doc, user)).toList(),
             );
          }

       }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you implemented your FeedWidget?

Comment: https://github.com/HighschoolStudentDeveloperYoon/feed_widget

Comment: Here is my feed_widget code..!

Answer (score 0):

hope you are fine,

I'm sorry as I misunderstood your question, so let's fix this by adding this code into your `feed_widget.dart`.

```
Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              '좋아요 5 개',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: const [
                Text(
                  "display name",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 8.0,
                ),
                Expanded(child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat")),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

- all you need here is to wrap your `text widget` with `expanded`, so it expands according to available content.
- [end result screenshot](https://ibb.co/THz93nC)
- Hope I could help, have a nice day :)

Comment: This code will contain in feed_widget?